# How to compare data from the same file in Hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a dataset look like this:

```
X, Y, Text  
52.2552455,-7.5450262,donec
57.6727414,-4.269928,nulla
13.0504833,50.3308509,curae
25.6538807,58.263232,magna
30.292001,57.8308498,massa
37.9273983,41.107107,mauris
37.444498,2.9372148,volutpat
```

`X,Y` values (longitude, latitude) represent a "spot".
What i want to achieve here is to group-compare each x,y (as one value - key) by the distance between each one of them.
The output should be:

```
 52.2552455,-7.5450262 [nulla,curae,mauris]
 57.6727414,-4.269928, [curae,massa]
 13.0504833,50.3308509, [massa]
 25.6538807,58.263232, [volutpat,magna,mauris]
 30.292001,57.8308498, [mauris]
 37.9273983,41.107107, [mauris,volutpat,magna,curae]
 37.444498,2.9372148, [volutpat]
```

The output means that: 52.2552455,-7.5450262 is neighbor-close to those 
strings ( nulla,curae,mauris).
Same for the all the x,y in the dataset.

I already wrote the code below:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
{           
    double spotX = 48.5672; 
    double spotY = 35.6897;
    String tweet = "";
    private int distX= 20;
    private int distY= 20;              
    private Text key1 = new Text();
    private Text value1 = new Text();


    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {   

            String line = value.toString();
            String[] results = line.split(",");

            for(int i=0; i < results.length; i+=3)
                {   

                    if (Double.parseDouble(results[i]) - spotX >= distX || Double.parseDouble(results[i+1]) - spotY >= distY )
                    {

                        key1.set(spotX + "," + spotY);
                        value1.set(results[i] + "," + results[i+1]+ "," +results[i+2]);
                        context.write(key1,value1); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
        }           
    }


public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{

     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
     {   

        List<String> vArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Text v : values)
        {
            vArrayList.add(v.toString());
        }
        context.write(key, new Text(vArrayList.toString()));             
     }
}
```

My code for now can only compare all the "spots" with a static spotX, SpotY declared in the map function.
Is there any way i could have a SpotX,SpotY in a dynamic way? I mean for each line, declare it as the one to compare with the others?
I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

In order for what you want to be possible, you must read the whole file at once. You cannot use the default `TextInputFormat` that splits on newlines of the input file.

You can find an implementation of a `WholeFileInputFormat` here.

http://bigdatathinker.blogspot.com/2014/01/reading-complete-file-in-mapreduce.html

And you would use it in your `Job` configuration of the main method. It looks like the key for that links' input format is `Text`, but the value is `BytesWritable`. You can find other examples, I'm sure for reading whole files.

The result you would want in your mapper would receive `"X, Y, Text\n52.2552455,-7.5450262,donec
\n57.6727414,-4.269928,nulla"`, (one long string) for example as your data to be processed.

From there, you can `value.split("\\n")`, and iterate over the lines, and do your distance calculations accordingly while you have all the data points.

All in all, you aren't having any benefit of using Hadoop here because 1) Your dataset seems small 2) It's no more performant than one Java process reading the file by itself.

Something that you may want to look into is K-means clustering because I think that's what you seem to be wanting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will read the article and come back if need to. 
Ps. My dataset is big enough! i just posted a sample of it!